# Puppeteer code can click on an element but Chrome Dev Tools can't

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Using `Puppeteer` I am able to find an element and click it:

```
var element = page.$$('SelectorPhrase');
element[0].click();
```

My code works and the element is found and clicked. Yet, on the Dev Tools (F12 on Chrome) I tried to find the same element and click it:

```
let e = document.querySelectorAll('SelectorPhrase')[0];
e.click();
```

The element is found via the dev tools, but is not actually clicked. After I call the click function I get a response of undefined.

Why the Puppeteer is able to click the element, and for the very same element the dev tool can't?

Comment: Hard to say without the site and a [mcve]. This could be caused by any number of behaviors, since every site is dynamic and unique in its behavior, so there's not much point in speculating. It could be something as simple as the element not existing when you run the console code. BTW -- use `page.$` and `querySelector()` if you're just going to do `[0]` right away and all you need is one element. Thanks.